# Entifty Framework search by Date range if input Date is not null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to search data as per date range and for that i want to check if input from and to date is enter than check date range otherwise get all records.
Below is my query.. please help me in this.

```
    from a in context.ABC
    join b in context.XYZ on a.ABCID equals b.Id
    where (txtFromDate.Text =="" ?  b.UploadDate.ToString().Contains(txtFromDate.Text) : 
    System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.UploadDate) >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Parse( txtFromDate.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB"))) &&
                                         txtToDate.Text==""?b.UploadDate.ToString().Contains(txtToDate.Text): System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.UploadDate) >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB"))))
group new { a, b } by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.UploadDate) into c
select new
{
UploadDate = System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.FirstOrDefault().b.UploadDate),
XYZ = c.Count(),
Lines = c.Sum(x => x.a.number)
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? We are not a free workforce, we all have our own jobs too... "can you write this for me" does not work here on stack overflow.

Comment: If i will enter from date and to date in search criteria then i want data within that date range and if i will not enter from and to date than it should load all data.. and i want to check it in query that if textboxes have from and to date or null

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Make new variables for your parameters before you get into the LINQ query.  It's bad practice to sanitise your parameters during a query.  As you can see, it makes it very messy.  I suggest using a "Date" type, and if the value would be null, actually put it as a date really far in the past/future.  This saves on extra workload later on...  e.g.

```
var dteParam1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFromDate.Text) ? new Date(1901, 1, 1) : Date.Parse(txtFromDate.Text);
```

Step 2: Make a date extension method that will check if a date is between two dates.  Then you can use it in your where clause, e.g.

```
b.UploadDate.IsBetween(dteParam1, dteParam2)
```

You'll have to find an example elsewhere on the internet...

Step 3: In your LINQ query, you can have a where clause like this:

```
where (b.UploadDate == null || b.UploadDate.IsBetween(dteParam1, dteParam2))
```

This works as follows:  If From date is null and To date is null, always return everything.  If From is null and To is not null, or visa versa, it will filter to be within that range.  If the database value is null, it'll always return that item no matter what you put as the filter.